# How to create a table with an attribute where the date is less than todays date

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints, relational-database

How can I create a table with an attribute whose date is less than today's date in PostgreSQL?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
CREATE TABLE Player(
dob DATE CHECK(dob < today's date) NOT NULL
/*other attributes and constraints omitted*/
);
```

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a problem with `check (dob < now())` ?

Comment: Nope, I don't get any problems with <code> check (dob < now()) </code> this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
check (dob < current_date)
```

It needs to be `current_date` not `now()` as a `date` will always (almost) be lower than `now` which is a `date` plus a `time`

```
select
    current_date,
    current_date::timestamp,
    now(),
    current_date < now(),
    current_date < current_date;
    date    |      timestamp      |              now              | ?column? | ?column? 
------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+----------+----------
 2017-04-04 | 2017-04-04 00:00:00 | 2017-04-04 11:54:39.703732+00 | t        | f
```

Answer (score 0):

**All credit goes to @Gordon Linoff for this answer.**

He suggested I use the `now()` function which PostgreSQL provides.

The `now()` function returns the current date and time.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html for more information.

My resulting table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Player(
dob DATE CHECK(dob < now()) NOT NULL
/*other attributes and constraints omitted*/
);
```

Comment: It is wrong. The correct version is `dob < current_date`

Comment: Ahh yes, I guess current_date would be correct as it returns the current date. But the now() function would return the current date and time. Would it make a difference if I used now() rather than current_date???? @ClodoaldoNeto

Comment: Check my answer